# How to convert UTM coordinate to DMS without zone?

Tags: qgis, dwg, autodesk

The `AutoDesk DWG TrueView 2017` can provide coordinate from the .dwg file, i think 5 digits is the UTM and it didnt provide the `Zone` area so i cannot convert to DMS, how to apply to QGIS GCP table?

[image]

Comment: What do you know about the drawing? Is the drawing geo-referenced? Can you post the drawing?

Comment: Seems very close to the equator (or possibly the pole) - 33251 metres is 33km. Is that expected?

Comment: I do not think those coordinates are UTM, Easting is really small. The departing value for a central meridian ia a UTM zone is 500,000m.  If you know in what part of the world  is your data yo can know the zone by searching the area in GoogleEarth. There you can configure to show utm coordinates and it will tell you also the zone (in carthographic notation. You must ask in what coordinate system is your data before trying to reproject it.

Comment: Even considering that your data provider  did not use the full digits for easting and/or northing you must try to search in what UTM zone your data is. For a GIS there are 60 utm "zones" north of the equator and 60 "zones" south of the equator.  If you know in what part of the world  is your data yo can know the zone by searching the area in GoogleEarth. There you can configure to show utm coordinates and it will tell you also the zone (in carthographic notation. You must ask in what coordinate system is your data before trying to reproject it.

Comment: @GerardoJimenez I don't think the small easting is much of a problem - it just means its 24.6km from the edge of the UTM band. The small northing however means its 33km from either the south pole (for S zones) or the equator (N zones) (or the other way round...)